# Javascript return "slowAES is not defined" in console

Tags: javascript, aes

I have a simple html within javasrcipt.

```
<html>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aes-js/3.1.1/index.js"></script>
    <script>
        function toNumbers(d) {
            var e = [];
            d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
                e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
            });
            return e
        }

        function toHex() {
            for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f <
                d.length; f++) e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
            return e.toLowerCase()
        }
        var a = toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),
            b = toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),
            c = toNumbers("04c05cdcc65887d199b5ed0029d66d18");
        document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
        location.href = "http://ttw2.epizy.com/?i=1";
    </script>
    <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
</body>

</html>
```

Every time I run it, the web interface just blank site. But when I open Console window of Google Chrome, I see that it return an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: slowAES is not defined
```

I don't know how to fix it at all.

Comment: `slowAES is not defined` means that no object with that name exists, because you haven't defined a variable with that name.  I see that you've included a link to the `aes-js` library, but it does not define a variable called `slowAES` either.  Look through the code in the javascript file you're including on your page to determine how to use it.  At quick glance, it looks like you need to use something like `slowAES = new AES()` to get started.

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: @TFrazee Can you explain more about this? I do as your suggest but it return new error that AES() is not define?

Comment: @Logan of course! My post is about Javascript! What are you doing?

Comment: @Meowth2018 It was initially tagged as `java`.

Comment: You can see again.

Answer (score 0):

In case no one has found the answer, you can download it from here:
https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/slowaes/source-archive.zip

Extract the ZIP, go to the folder slowaes, then trunk, then js, and copy aes.js to your project.
Include/import the aes.js file to your project.
Note: it's licensed under Apache License v2

Else you can download a copy of the aes.js directly from iFastNet/InfinityFree here:

- http://epizy.com/aes.js
  or here:
- http://rf.gd/aes.js

But I'm not sure if there are edits or not, and if the license is the same.